# requestLocationUpdates vs getLastLocation

Tags: java, android, location, locationmanager

Does calling requestLocationUpdates from LocationManager update the location returned by getLastLocation?

ie, can i do this:

1. call getLastLocation. it returns null, then:
2. call requestLocationUpdates;
3. receive onLocationChanged on my listener, and do nothing

And after that, call getLastLocation and get something !=null?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add and example ?

Answer (score 1):

getLastLocation will return the last location if LocationManager has a previous location reading. If LocationManager doesn't have a previous location then null will be returned.

requestLocationUpdates will request ongoing location updates until you unsubscribe from location updates.

Further details can be found here:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

The following explanation is given on why getLastLocation might return null:

```
Location is turned off in the device settings. The result could be null even if the last location was previously retrieved because disabling location also clears the cache.

The device never recorded its location, which could be the case of a new device or a device that has been restored to factory settings.

Google Play services on the device has restarted, and there is no active Fused Location Provider client that has requested location after the services restarted. To avoid this situation you can create a new client and request location updates yourself. For more information, see Receiving Location Updates.
```